# Error KillProcess in visual 2019 with .net framework 4.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a mvc 5 project with .net framework 4.6 and when I try to compile my project I get the following error:

> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
> Error       La tarea "KillProcess" no se pudo cargar desde el ensamblado C:\seguros-mundial-portal-autenticacion-firmas\PortalFirmas.BackOffice\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build\net472....\tasks\DotNetCompilerPlatformTasks.dll. No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///portal-autenticacion-firmas\PortalFirmas.BackOffice\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\tasks\DotNetCompilerPlatformTasks.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. Confirme que la declaración  sea correcta; que el ensamblado y todas sus dependencias estén disponibles; y que la tarea contenga una clase public que implemente Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.    PortalFirmas.ServicioPortalFirmas

[image]

It is an error that has little information on the web and I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: Also v4.7.2 .net framerwork

Comment: you have tried to restore the NuGet packages?